# How to create a 2D array from a list of list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of lists that looks something like this:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

I want to create a 2 by 2 array with the first 2 elements at the top and the last two at the bottom, something like:

```
[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]
```

What I tried so far was reshape using:

```
np.array(arr).reshape(2,2)
```

However whenever I do that I get a *ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged*
What exactly am I missing or how can I get this to work?

Comment: Can you show what *exactly* you try to get as a result? (not "something like")

Comment: What's the `np.array(arr).shape`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `list` comprehension:

```
nparr = np.array([arr[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(arr), 2)]
print(nparr)
```

Output:

```
[[[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
 [[7 8 9] [10 11 12]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go for something like this, which `reshapes` the `numpy` array.

```
import numpy as np
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
out = np.reshape(sum([], arr), (-1, 3))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [10 11 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is not exactly possible like this but this could satisfy your needs:

```
arr2 = [arr[:2], arr[2:]]
np.array(arr2)
```

This returns something like this:

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]]

 [[ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that *arr* has a total of 12 elements. You can not arrange 12 elements in a 2,2 manner using reshape.

This is a possible solution for you

```py
 np.array(arr).reshape(2, 6)
```

Output

```py
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: did you try `reshape(2,2,3)`?

Comment: I did, it gives the same output as in umgefahren's answer above. I thought reshape(2, 6) was closer to op's required output.

Comment: The OP is a bit unclear.  He accepted an answer that produced (2,2,3) shape.  (see my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion as to what you want:

```
In [93]: alist = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Making an array from the list:

```
In [94]: np.array(alist)
Out[94]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
In [95]: _.shape
Out[95]: (4, 3)
```

That's a total of 12 elements.  `reshape` has to match that:

```
In [96]: np.array(alist).reshape(2,2,3)
Out[96]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
In [97]: _.shape
Out[97]: (2, 2, 3)
```

The accepted answer does the same thing:

```
In [99]: np.array([alist[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(alist), 2)])
Out[99]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
```

In nested list form:

```
In [100]: [alist[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(alist), 2)]
Out[100]: [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]
```

When defining/displaying 2 and 3d arrays, the [] are more important than the line breaks and spacing.